# Combine pandas DataFrame rows with overlapping data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where on occasion a row of data ends up being split across two rows of a Dataframe. I am able to isolate these rows and would like to combine the two rows together, unfortunately it is not always straight forward as the data is assigned upstream on a first in basis to the DB.

Example df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'id':[1,2,2,3,3],
     'a1':[1,1,np.NaN,1,np.NaN],
     'b1':[1,2,np.NaN,2,np.NaN],
     'c1':[1,3,np.NaN,3,5],
     'c2':[1,4,np.NaN,4,6],
     'c3':[1,np.NaN,5,np.NaN,7],
     'c4':[1,np.NaN,6,np.NaN,np.NaN],
     'c5':[1,np.NaN,7,np.NaN,np.NaN],
     'd1':[1,np.NaN,8,np.NaN,8]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    id  a1  b1  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  d1
0   1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1   2   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   2   NaN NaN NaN NaN 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0
3   3   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   3   NaN NaN 5.0 6.0 7.0 NaN NaN 8.0
```

For clarity duplicates are on 'id'. And the intention is to have a single row per ID within df.

Scenario 1 (ID = 2): index 2 values 5,6,7,8 would replace the NaN values in index 1 directly above.

Scenario 2 (ID = 3): index 4 values 5,6,7 would need to move to columns C3, C4, C5 within index 3 and value 8 (d1) would replace the NaN value in d1/index 3

This occurs multiple times within a large dataset and varies about the column in which the split happens so I would ideally need to be able to do this dynamically where a duplicate ID is found.

EDIT: For Additional Scenario

```
d = {'id':[1,4,4],
 'a1':[1,1,np.NaN],
 'b1':[2,2,np.NaN],
 'c1':[3,3,5],
 'c2':[4,4,6],
 'c3':[5,np.NaN,np.NaN],
 'c4':[6,np.NaN,np.NaN],
 'c5':[7,np.NaN,np.NaN],
 'd1':[8,np.NaN,8]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)

    id  a1  b1  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  d1
0   1   1.0 2.0 3   4   5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0
1   4   1.0 2.0 3   4   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   4   NaN NaN 5   6   NaN NaN NaN 8.0
```

Scenario 3 (ID = 4): the same as scenario 2 however c5 (id4) would remain as a NaN value in this case.

Comment: do you always have the perfect number of values and all the rest NaNs?

Comment: @mozway no I don't always have the exact number of values, you should typically get at least one value for each alpha column e.g. [a1,b1,c1,d1] then you could get any number of values in this case for c. It is typical that you may only have a handful of rows in a DF that has values for all columns and then any number of rows with values in between c1 and c(n)

Comment: can you update your example to reflect this? and provide the details on which column has which role?

Comment: How do you decide on which columns should be unshifted? Will it always be d1? or is it based on pattern? can it vary among groups?

Comment: @mozway in this instance (and typically) there are multiple data points captured during time period c (typically 1-6) depending on the duration of the recoding. The data is recoded and injected in a first recoded basis. In this case resulting in the duplicate row points actually being the 3rd and 4th recorded data point for time period c. Point d1 should never become a problem as the split in recoding takes place prior to the d time period so should not have any overlapping values. I hope that make sense.

Comment: check the updated answer ;)

Comment: @mozway thank you for this it seems to work very effectively. One strange thing that is happening (I am forced to use an old version of Pandas 0.23) is that when I return the output as a variable it returns it with a multilevel column index. level 0 [a, b, c, d], level 1 [a1,b1,c1... etc]. I then have to reassign the columns using df2.columns.droplevel(0) which seems to work fine other than having to reassign 'id' as a column name. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Honestly, this is a quite old version now. I don't remember all the changes ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241656/discussion-between-sidoescoding-and-mozway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ideal number of values to fill the NaNs

Assuming you always have the ideal number of values, you can flatten per group without NaNs:

```
(df.set_index('id')
   .groupby(level=0)
   .apply(lambda d: d.stack().dropna().set_axis(df.columns[1:]))
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   id   a1   b1   c1   c2   c3   c4   c5   d1
0   1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1   2  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
2   3  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

###### alternative for an arbitrary number of "id"/grouping columns:

```
id_cols = ['id']
(df.set_index(id_cols)
   .groupby(level=range(len(id_cols)))
   .apply(lambda d: d.stack().dropna().set_axis(list(df.drop(columns=id_cols))))
   .reset_index()
)
```

#### filling values per group of columns

In this alternative the columns are grouped per `Xn` where `X` is a non-digit word and `n` the sublevel.

Here I used a double `groupby`, once on the rows, once on the columns:

```
def flat(d):
    return (d.groupby(d.columns.str.extract('(^\D+)', expand=False), axis=1)
             .apply(lambda d: pd.DataFrame([sorted(d.values.ravel(),
                                                   key=pd.isna)[:len(d.columns)]],
                                           columns=d.columns)
                    )).iloc[0]

(df2.set_index('id')
   .groupby(level=0)
   .apply(flat)
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
0  id   a1   b1   c1   c2   c3   c4   c5   d1
0   1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
1   4  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  NaN  8.0
```